# flutter_janus_client example crashed with fatal error

Tags: flutter, webrtc, semantics, sdp, janus

I was trying out the example of flutter_janus_client package from https://github.com/flutterjanus/flutter_janus_client.

When I ran videoRoom.dart from the example and hit connect, it gave me a fatal error:

```
E/rtc     ( 8007): #
E/rtc     ( 8007): # Fatal error in: ../../../../usr/local/google/home/sakal/code/webrtc-aar-release/src/pc/peer_connection.cc, line 1989
E/rtc     ( 8007): # last system error: 0
E/rtc     ( 8007): # Check failed: IsUnifiedPlan()
E/rtc     ( 8007): # GetTransceivers is only supported with Unified Plan SdpSemantics.
```

and the app lost connection.

Since the error is about Unified Plan, I added "isUnifiedPlan: true" to JanusClient:

```
j = JanusClient(iceServers: [
        RTCIceServer(
            url: "stun:40.85.216.95:3478",
            username: "onemandev",
            credential: "SecureIt"),
        RTCIceServer(
            url: "turn:40.85.216.95:3478",
            username: "onemandev",
            credential: "SecureIt")
      ], server: [
        'https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/janus',
        'https://janus.onemandev.tech/janus',
        // 'wss://janus.onemandev.tech/janus/websocket',
        // 'https://janus.onemandev.tech/janus',
      ], withCredentials: true, apiSecret: "SecureIt",
          isUnifiedPlan: true);
```

But it didn't change anything.

So how do I fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: Have u found a solution by any chance? Having the same issue.

Comment: flutter_janus_client 2.0.0-beta just came out. it will work.